# SQL - сумма значений столбца

Tags: запрос, db2, база-данных, sql

Привет!
Дана таблица с информацией о ценных бумагах на продажу с именем бумаги, количеством и ценой. Пример значений таблицы для одной ценной бумаги Cisco:

```
   name   call_volume  price
1- Cisco  300          27
2- Cisco  150          26
3- Cisco  50           26
```

есть такой запрос:

```
select
o.o_stock as name,
sum(o.o_amount) as call_volume,
o.o_limit as price

from orders o, orders calls

where
o.o_stock = 'Cisco'
and o.o_stock = calls.o_stock
and o.o_limit <= calls.o_limit
and calls.o_type = 'CALL'
and o.O_ID = calls.O_ID

group by o.o_stock, o.o_limit     
order by o.o_limit DESC
```

Результат запроса:

```
   name    call_volume   price
1- Cisco   300           27
2- Cisco   200           26
```

Но необходимо получить:

```
   name   call_volume  price
1- Cisco  300          27
2- Cisco  500          26
```

т.е. у нас есть максимальная price (27), тогда volume = сумма всех ценных бумаг по этой макс. price (27)
далее цена меньше макс. price (26), тогда volume = сумма всех ценных бумаг по этой цене плюс всех ценных бумаг по большей price (в данном случае 27)
если бы у нас была еще одна строка, скажем :

```
 name      call_volume  price
    1- Cisco  300          27
    2- Cisco  150          26
    3- Cisco  50           26
    4- Cisco  100          25
```

тогда необходимый результат был бы:

```
  name     call_volume  price
    1- Cisco  300          27
    2- Cisco  500          26
    3- Cisco  600          25
```

Вопрос...КАК?? :))
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ееейй!!!! то, что нужно!!! спасибо огромное!!! все работает теперь как надо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Это называется [накопительными итогами](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_running_totals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Вот код для вашей проблемы:

[Code project: Calculating simple running totals in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/300785/Calculating-simple-running-totals-in-SQL-Server)